# Can anyone help me with jquery coding

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
       $("#id_"+i).hover(function(){ // i in this line is 1->7
             alert(i); // i in this line alway is 7 (I want i: 1-7 )
       });
    }
});
```

I use onmoveover and onmouseout in html to call function is not problem but i see it so long coding, anyone help me to solve this problem. Thankyou so much.

Comment: _but i see it so long coding_ - Can you clarify what this means?

Comment: I found a solution: 

$(document).ready(function(){
var func=[]
   for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
       (function(u){
            func[u] = function(){
                  alert(u);
             }
         })(i)
       $("#id_"+i).hover(func[i]);
    }
});

// but i think func[u] had make many (i think 7th in end for) anyone help me  to solve to shorter

Answer (score 0):

Use this shorter alternative (the selector '[id^="id_"]' means "id that starts with id_"):

```js
$('[id^="id_"]').hover(function () {
    alert(this.id.replace('id_', ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id_0">div 0</div>
<br>
<div id="id_1">div 1</div>
<br>
<div id="id_2">div 2</div>
<br>
<div id="id_3">div 3</div>
<br>
<div id="id_4">div 4</div>
<br>
<div id="id_5">div 5</div>
<br>
<div id="id_6">div 6</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Thank your answer but that not solve my problem if i<10000 you can write that.